# Split a number equally between coloumns kinda eg. 12 sweets, 10 people. 2 people get 2 sweets each, the rest get 1

Tags: javascript, math

Hi I have a table with 10 coloumns and what I want to do is take a value from the user and split it out between the 10 so for example if the user enters 10 i want the result to be

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

if the user enters 12 i want the result to be

2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

etc

I have tried dividing the user input by 10 but it doesn't work especialy when you don't have a whole number.

I'm using javascript, would be great to get your help or an idea on what the formulae would be

```
var userInput = 12
var colCount = 10


   for (var i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++)
            {
                document.write(userInput / colCount);
            }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you'd have two zero columns if the user enters 12. Is this a type, or is there some deep magic going on here?

Comment: Sorry mistake on my part! it would be 
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var userInput = 12
var colCount = 10

var quocient = Math.floor(userInput/colCount);
var remainder = userInput%colCount;

for (var i = 0; i < colCount ; i++)
{
    var num = (i<remainder)?quocient+1:quocient;
    document.write(num);
}
```

Note that the loop has to be strictly less than 10 if you initialize the "i" to 0...

Comment: That's awesome, worked for me although I changed i to 1 the < to <= Thanks Is it possible to explain this (i<=remainder)?quocient+1:quocient; so i understand how it works?

Comment: this is the same as: if(i<=remainder) { num=quocient+1; } else { num=quocient; }

Answer (score 1):

```
js> qty = 12
12
js> ppl = 10
10
js> for (i = 0; i < ppl; i++) {
print(Math.floor(qty / ppl) + (i < qty % ppl))
}
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```